# different results jsp mysql

Tags: mysql, tomcat, phpmyadmin

I'm facing a trouble with a table in a MySQL database when accessing it with Tomcat.

When I insert a new line using either phpmyadmin or mysql on command line it is stored normally in my table. If I do the same using the same statement over JSP/java it seems to be stored normally, and when I make a query over JSP/java I see the line I inserted. But this line cannot be seen on phpmyadmin or mysql command line. If I restart Tomcat this line disappears when I query via JSP.

It looks like my Tomcat is dealing with an image of the table and not the real table. I don't know if it's a bad option I used when I created the table with phpmyadmin

I'm using Tomcat7 and mysql-server-5.6 on a VPS. All tables are in the same database and i'm using the same pool database for all. All the rest of tables worked fine for years.

This would be the insert statement that is generating my Java code:

> INSERT INTO Pedido
>   (Id,IdSupervisor,Concepto,Importe,ImporteTotal,Moneda,TipoTransaccion,Terminal,Comercio,Fecha,URLAction,Dsdate,Dsterminal,Dsmerchantcode,Dsresponse,Dsorder,Dscurrency,Comments)
>   VALUES
>   (505,'0','null','0.0','0.0','null','null','null','null','1970-01-01','null','1970-01-01','null','null','null','null','null','null')

Comment: Share a SQL insertion java code, No tomcat neither java itself nothing knows about mysql. MySQL driver works with mySQL

Comment: @jaume how do you insert it in JSP/Java? you have to show the code

Comment: I put it in my post. Thanks

Comment: @jaume Did you tried run this command in phpmyadmin? Was it successful?

Comment: @jaume `If I do the same using the same statement over JSP/java it seems to be stored normally, and when I make a query over JSP/java I see the line I inserted` Are you sure that this is same db?

Comment: @Mark. Both using phpmyadmin interface and using mysql command line, i can copy&paste the above statement and the data is stored permanently. Note taht in command line i have to add "mydatabasename." before table. So it seems syntax is ok.

Comment: @Mark. Yes it would be a good hint to think i'm accessing a different DB, but as far as I know, it's the same. Both tables that work fine and this one are accessing, from the same VPS, to the same DataSource `DataSource ds = (DataSource) c.lookup("java:comp/env/pool_isr");` that is defined in my server.xml

Comment: Another data: the rebel table never worked well

Comment: The fact is that if I restart Tomcat and after it i do a java/jsp query the values shown are the ones made through phpmyadmin/mysql command, and the ones done by jsp/java are simply gone.

Comment: If I drop the table, statements and queries from Java/JSP return that the table is missing, logically, and this makes me think that at the end there are not different databases as suggested before

Comment: @jaume provide the JSP code than you using.

Comment: @Mark, thanks for your help, really. I was comming to post I solved it. At the end, as I expected, it was something on how I created the messy table. Changing the storing engine from "innoDB" to "MyISAM" did the trick. I'm still confused as I have some of my working table as InnoDB and these are working fine... i'll check MySQL docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, as I expected, it was something on how I created the messy table. Changing the storing engine from "innoDB" to "MyISAM" did the trick.